# Change treeview sub node colour text colour and image

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I'm using the below to search for a node named "Archive" and then change its colour to red and image index.

```
Dim d As String = "Archive"
            For i = 0 To tvProgress.Nodes.Count - 1
                If tvProgress.Nodes(i).Text = d Then
                    tvProgress.Nodes(i).ForeColor = Color.Red
                    tvProgress.Nodes(i).ImageIndex = 1
                End If
            Next
```

As you see from the below image the node "Archive" has some structure underneath. I would also like to change the colour and image index of these as well. These are not a static node name like "Archive" so I can't simply repeat the process.

There are also other nodes in the treeview that need to be left as the default Blue Folder, Black Text

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use this code, just set `d` to the node you want to search for, and `p` to anything you want to preserve.

```
'This stores every node in the TreeView
Dim allNodes As New List(Of TreeNode)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'the node you want to search for
    Dim d As String = "Archive"
    'the node you want to preserve
    Dim p As String = "Preserve"
    CallRecursive(TreeView1)
    For Each n As TreeNode In allNodes
        If n.Text = d Then
            n.ForeColor = Color.Red
            n.ImageIndex = 1
        ElseIf Not n.Text = p Then
            Dim path As String = n.FullPath
            Dim l As List(Of String) = path.Split("\").ToList()
            If l.Contains(d) Then
                If l.IndexOf(n.Text) > l.IndexOf(d) Then
                    n.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    n.ImageIndex = 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub GetRecursive(ByVal n As TreeNode)
    allNodes.Add(n)
    Dim aNode As TreeNode
    For Each aNode In n.Nodes
        GetRecursive(aNode)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CallRecursive(ByVal aTreeView As Windows.Forms.TreeView)
    allNodes.Clear()
    Dim n As TreeNode
    For Each n In aTreeView.Nodes
        GetRecursive(n)
    Next
End Sub
```

The procedure used to get every node in the `TreeView` is called **recursive** procedure, which basically means that `GetRecursive()` will call itself until it has been through every node in your `TreeView`. Thanks to this, this code will go through any `TreeView`, regardless of depth.


This is the `TreeView` I used to test this code, *before* the code is run:


[image: Before:]


And *after* the code is run:


[image: And after:]


I hope this helps, any problems and I will try and help.

---

### Edit:

If you just want to format **all** nodes under "Archive", use this slightly modified code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'the node you want to search for
    Dim d As String = "Archive"
    CallRecursive(TreeView1)
    For Each n As TreeNode In allNodes
        If n.Text = d Then
            n.ForeColor = Color.Red
            n.ImageIndex = 1
        Else
            Dim path As String = n.FullPath
            Dim l As List(Of String) = path.Split("\").ToList()
            If l.Contains(d) Then
                If l.IndexOf(n.Text) > l.IndexOf(d) Then
                    n.ForeColor = Color.Red
                    n.ImageIndex = 1
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub GetRecursive(ByVal n As TreeNode)
    allNodes.Add(n)
    Dim aNode As TreeNode
    For Each aNode In n.Nodes
        GetRecursive(aNode)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CallRecursive(ByVal aTreeView As Windows.Forms.TreeView)
    allNodes.Clear()
    Dim n As TreeNode
    For Each n In aTreeView.Nodes
        GetRecursive(n)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this is great thanks but I'm not sure if it will work for me. Basically the nodes under the 'Archive' node are added by a user and will not will be the same name. I think I want to say that any node that is under the 'Archive' node then that should be formatted in the red.

Comment: Then simply remove the `ElseIf Not n.Text = p Then` and the matching `End If`, but **not** anything inside it, I will update my answer.